# nvidia simpleDevLibCUBLAS error

Tags: makefile, cuda, cublas

My goal is to insert a cublas process in my cuda kernel so i looked at simpleDevLibCUBLAS example.

My compilation leads to that:

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64      -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o simpleDevLibCUBLAS kernels.o simpleDevLibCUBLAS.o  -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt
```

> nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'cublasCreate_v2' in
>   'kernels.o' (target: sm_35) nvlink error   : Undefined reference to
>   'cublasSgemm_v2' in 'kernels.o' (target: sm_35) nvlink error   :
>   Undefined reference to 'cublasDestroy_v2' in 'kernels.o' (target:
>   sm_35) Makefile:239 : la recette pour la cible « simpleDevLibCUBLAS »
>   a échouée make: *** [simpleDevLibCUBLAS] Erreur 255

I try to modify the Makefile but nothing works.

Can somehone give me a tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your linker does not know where to find the libraries specified by `-lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt`

You could tell it with the link option `-L/path/to/cuda/libs`